# JQ Map to String

Tags: jq

I'm trying to transform a map to a string of key/value pairs with JQ.

I'd like to transform this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "qux"
}
```

Into this:

```
-var="foo=bar" -var="baz=qux"
```

I've managed to get it close with this:

```
jq -r ". | to_entries | .[] | (\"-var=\\\"\" + .key + \"=\" + .value + \"\\\"\")"
```

Which gives me:

```
-var="foo=bar"
-var="baz=qux"
```

But I can't figure out the last step to have it join them with a space instead of a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `[ ... ] | join( " " )`.

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries | map( "-var=\"\( .key + "=" + .value )\"" ) | join( " " )'
```

But it looks like you're building a shell command, so you should also use `@sh` (or whatever's appropriate for the shell you use) to properly quote the values.

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries | map( @sh "-var=\( .key + "=" + .value )" ) | join( " " )'
```

For example,

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "qux",
  "moo": "a'b\"c"
}
```

results in

```
-var='foo=bar' -var='baz=qux' -var='moo=a'\''b"c'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/U4AU_riD7pt) on jqplay.

You'd run the command using

```bash
eval "mycommand $( ... | jq ... )"
```

Notes:

- No code injection bugs.
- Works in all sh-like shells.
- Even works with values containing Line Feeds.

Answer (score 1):

From the output given, it seems you want to pass the result to another command, you can try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -d '' -t options < <(jq -j -r 'to_entries[]|"-var=\(.key)=\(.value)\u0000"' input.json)

echo another-command "${options[@]}"
# Output : another-command -var=foo=bar -var=baz=qux
```

Comment: Note that this relies on bash features that aren't available in other sh shells.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `join()` function in JQ to join the key/value pairs with a space instead of a new line.

```
jq -r ". | to_entries | map(\"-var=\\\"\(.key)=\(.value)\\\"\") | join(\" \")"
```

Comment: This suffers from a [code injection bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).